# Argument principle - contour integral around one pole

Tags: residue-calculus, riemann-zeta

When I compute this contour integral around $s=1$ I get 0.
$$\frac1{{2 \pi  i}}\bigg(\int_{\frac{9}{10}-i}^{\frac{11}{10}-i} \frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)} \, ds+\int_{\frac{11}{10}-i}^{\frac{11}{10}+i} \frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)} \, ds+\int_{\frac{9}{10}+i}^{\frac{9}{10}-i} \frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)} \, ds+\int_{\frac{11}{10}+i}^{\frac{9}{10}+i} \frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)} \, ds\bigg)=0$$
But according to argument principle it should be equal to N-P where N is number of zeros and P number of poles. So the result should be -1 as there is one pole at s=1 inside contour and no zeros.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: We can't tell what went wrong without seeing what you did. All we can say now is "you miscalculated the integral".

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I am looking at it already half a day and can not spot any mistake. Can you confirm my integration limits are OK?

Comment: I got these four numbers for the four integrals: ${0. -1.85456 i,-0.105946-0.164495 i,0. +2.18355 i,0.105946 -0.164495 i}$. Summing them gives me zero.

Comment: The integral limits are okay. _How_ did you evaluate the integrals?

Comment: I used Mathematica. Are the four values wrong?

Comment: It must be some silly mistake.

Comment: No idea. Well, we know that at least one of them must be wrong, but I have no idea which. Can you let Mathematica tell you how it computed them? (Something like a "verbose" option?)

Comment: Nothing special. Simple numerical evaluation. Am I going to do the same with SAGE.

Comment: reuns So the integrals were computed correctly? But I used wrong method?

Comment: I don't care at all of the numerical evaluation of your integrals. We can discuss of how to define $\log \zeta(s)$ though

Comment: It looks like Mathematica goofed on the third integral, that should be not too different from $-2i(\gamma + \arctan 10) \approx -4.1\, i$ according to my mental arithmetic.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Interesting! That would give us the required roughly -1 instead of 0. How did you compute it?

Comment: Using two terms of the Laurent expansion, $$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = -\frac{1}{s-1} + \gamma + O(s-1).$$ Then, since $\lvert s-1\rvert$ doesn't become much larger than $1$ on the contour, ignoring the contribution of the remaining part shouldn't introduce a significant error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See any text on complex analysis. For $\gamma(t),t \in (0,1)$ a small enough closed-contour around $s=1$ in positive direction $$\int_\gamma \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}ds \overset{def}=\int_0^1\frac{\zeta'(\gamma(t))}{\zeta(\gamma(t))}\gamma'(t)dt = -\int_\gamma \frac{1}{s-1}ds+\int_\gamma f(s)ds = -2i\pi$$ where $f(s) = \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+\frac{1}{s-1}$ is analytic on a simply connected open set containing the small enough contour, [thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) 
 it has an analytic anti-derivative $F(s)= \int_1^s f(z)dz$ thus $\int_\gamma f(s)ds = F(s)|_{\gamma(0)}^{\gamma(1)} = 0$.

Comment: reuns OK I can compute it this way. (Same as making Laurent series at s=1 and looking at coefficient $1/(s-1)$) But what was wrong with my original method? And why the same method works with say $\sin '(s-1)/\sin (s-1)$ at s=1 but not with $\zeta '(s)/\zeta (s)$? Sorry if I do not understand you correctly.

Comment: @azerbajdzan You can also understand what fails in your numerical evaluation. Everything is about the branches, in particular the branches of $\log(s-1)$, the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{s-1}$.

Comment: reuns Sorry, but not yet. :-D I do not see any difference between $\zeta(s)$ and $1/\sin(s-1)$ at s=1. On $1/\sin(s-1)$ my numerical evaluation worked but on $\zeta(s)$ not.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Yes the problem is that you don't see any difference between $\log(s-1)$ and $\log(s-1)+2i\pi$, and hence between $\log \zeta(s)$ and $\log \zeta(s)+2i\pi$, whereas there is one.

Comment: OK, I will mark your answer as correct although I do not understand why the method works for one function and fails for another. Maybe some day I will understand it.

Comment: It fails because you trust your CAS instead of looking at the maths : I have shown why, for $\zeta'/\zeta$ or $\sin'/\sin$, it reduces to integrating $\frac{1}{s-1}$, thus to define the correct branch of $\log(s-1)$